# JavaFX non-modular project Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, runtime-error

I'm trying to get JavaFX to work on windows 10 with a non-modular project. I have Java version 14.0.1 and JavaFX version 15.0.1. I followed the instructions listed [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) exactly, but when I run the program it gives me this error:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:261)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:273)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more
```

I've also looked at these questions([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561986/how-to-solve-the-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-d3d-sw-problem), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143258/javafx-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-d3d-sw-on-eclipse-win10), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60656844/how-to-solve-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-d3d-sw-when-running)), and I did what they said but I still get an error when I run it. I downloaded the JavaFX sdk file from the [official download website](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), and my VM options are:

```
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

I've tried changing the module path to a path in a different location as well as a path with no spaces to no avail. I've also tried using Eclipse, Netbeans, and no IDE (all setup instructions were from [the official website](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)), but none of them work. The program which I'm trying to run is a just a test program.

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            // create a new Text shape
            Text messageText = new Text("Hello World! Lets learn JavaFX.");

            // stack page
            StackPane root = new StackPane();

            // add Text shape to Stack Pane
            root.getChildren().add(messageText);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Response to the answer

Sorry for the late reply, but I tried to put what you said in the VM options, which I think is what you mean, but I got an error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class run.jvmargs=--module-path
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: run.jvmargs=--module-path.
```

I also tried running it without the run.jvmargs= but it also doesn't work. I got the below error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class \
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \
```

By the way the specific VM options that I have are below.

```
run.jvmargs=--module-path "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\\lib" \
    --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web \
    --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.network=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.dom=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.scenario.animation.shared=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=ALL-UNNAMED
```

EDIT - 2:
[image: file structures on the right]

Answer (score 0):

my project also uses this run.jvmargs property. HTere's

```
run.jvmargs=--module-path "D:\\Libraries\\Java9\\openjfx-13.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\\lib" \
    --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web \
    --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.network=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.dom=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.scenario.animation.shared=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=ALL-UNNAMED // <<-- notice this thing
```

also, make sure you're using \\ instead of \

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I still have an error with your VM options. I have the details edited at the bottom of my questions. If you don't mind, could you please take a look at that?

Comment: hi, @yakatoi , there is another parameter in that file called `main.class` i think you should set it to `sample.Main` to correspond with the Application class you're using to start the project. as a verifier, you should use `this.getClass().getName()` to get that string.

Comment: thanks for the response! I'm a bit confused by what you mean. Are you talking about the package name in the program or the file structure of the project? If it's about the file structure, I have a pic of it in the question. If its about the package name, I changed it from sample to sample.main. but nothing happened.

Comment: Update! I kinda fixed the problem, not really. I just switched to Java SE 8 cuz I'm fairly kind of maybe sure the project I'm working on works with SE8. Kind of a temp solution, but it works. Thanks for all the help tho!

Comment: right, so java uses packages. these are relatively similar to folder structures. if you have a folder `X` inside folder `A`, with Class `C` in it, it will be `X.A.C` ... `X` and `A` are `packages`. When you compile/run a program, the classpath compiler uses folder structures to establish paths to classes... so it will define it's `X.A.C` path for instantiating class C. Since you're using Class C to run the application ... you'll need the  `X.A.C` reference set up as `main.class` in the `project.properties` file

Comment: maybe i'm overcomplicating things... think of it like breadcrumbs... the package.class aka `x.a.c` example above is basically the route to your class. If you're using a main class to start your application, you need that route. You can easily get this route by adding temporary code somewhere, with `System.out.printline(this.getClass().getName());` and copy the resulting string in the `main.class` property of the `project.properties` file in which you've added `--add-modules` stuff

Comment: it should go without saying that you should paste that system.out line in the class you want to set as the main class, and not some other one.